# PROMPT not taking input and getting a compiler error

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a procedure in PL/SQL using Oracle Developer that takes input from PROMPT and outputs with exception handlers if no input is entered.  My Prompt window shows 'please enter a value for the p_first_name' and not what I have in '... '.  After entering data in the prompts I get the following error:

> ```
> Error(6,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROMPT" when expecting 
> one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
> ```

#### Code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON


CREATE PROCEDURE print_name (first_name IN varchar, last_name varchar, 
title varchar) IS

ACCEPT p_first_name PROMPT 'Please enter a first name:'

ACCEPT p_last_name PROMPT 'Please enter a second name:'

ACCEPT p_title PROMPT 'Please enter a second name:'

DECLARE

first_name varchar  :=&p_first_name;
last_name varchar   :=&p_last_name;
title varchar       :=&p_title;


first_null EXCEPTION;
last_null EXCEPTION;
title_null EXCEPTION;

BEGIN



IF first_name IS NULL THEN
raise first_null;
END IF;

IF last_name IS NULL THEN
raise last_null;
END IF;

IF title IS NULL THEN
raise title_null;
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(last_name || ',' || first_name || ' ' || title);

EXCEPTION
WHEN first_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a first name.');

WHEN last_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a last name.');

WHEN title_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a title.');

END;
/
```

After entering a first, last, and title, I expect to print:

> ```
> Doe, Jane Ms.
> ```

If any value IS NULL,  I expect the exception handlers to print.

So far, I only get the following error:

> ```
> Error(6,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROMPT" when expecting 
> one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_name (first_name IN varchar, last_name 
            varchar, title varchar) IS






first_null EXCEPTION;
last_null EXCEPTION;
title_null EXCEPTION;

BEGIN




IF first_name IS NULL THEN
raise first_null;
END IF;

IF last_name IS NULL THEN
raise last_null;
END IF;

IF title IS NULL THEN
raise title_null;
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(last_name || ',' || first_name || ' ' || title);

EXCEPTION
WHEN first_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a first name.');

WHEN last_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a last name.');

WHEN title_null THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You must enter a title.');

END;
/
```

then while executing procedure use prompt as prompt works externally not in a stored procedure

like

```
 ACCEPT p_first_name  char PROMPT 'Please enter a first name:';
 ACCEPT p_last_name char PROMPT 'Please enter a second name:';

       ACCEPT p_title_name char  PROMPT 'Please enter a second name:';


 exec print_name('&p_first_name','&p_last_name','&p_title_name');
```

[image]